# org.eclipse.swt jar updated and OS.FindWindow is gone

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, swt

In my project, I had a method which was using org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS. The jar that I was using were org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-3.106.0.jar and org.eclipse.swt-3.106.0.jar

While I am working on my project, I had to switch the version of those jar to 116.0. Then, I figured out that OS.FindWindow method were gone. I tried to find out the other way to cover OS.FindWindow method but I had no luck.
Is there anyone had some Idea?

Here is my code

```
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.TCHAR;

import mypackage.DEFINE;

public class WindowUtil {

    
    public static void fireMessage(int msg,long wParam ,long lParam) {
        
        
        TCHAR  win_name = new TCHAR(OS.CP_INSTALLED, DEFINE.WIN_TITLE,true);
        long hWnd = OS.FindWindow(null,win_name);
        //x64
        boolean blan = OS.PostMessage(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        //x86
//      boolean blan = OS.PostMessage((int)hWnd, msg, (int)wParam, (int)lParam);
        
    }
}
```

what I tried:

I added jna-5.13.0.jar and jna-platform-4.5.0.jar. And I changed my code like below.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.TCHAR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

public class WindowUtil {


public static void fireMessage(int msg,long wParam ,long lParam) {
    
    
    TCHAR  win_name = new TCHAR(0x1, DEFINE.WIN_TITLE,true);
    HWND hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow(null, DEFINE.WIN_TITLE);
    long handle = Pointer.nativeValue(hwnd.getPointer());
    //x64
    boolean blan = OS.PostMessage(handle, msg, wParam, lParam);
    //x86
//      boolean blan = OS.PostMessage((int)hWnd, msg, (int)wParam,  (int)lParam);
    
}
}
```

then I got errors like this.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could
not initialize class com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase
atcom.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HANDLE.fromNative(WinNT.java:1366) at com.sun.jna.NativeMappedConverter.fromNative(NativeMappedConverter.java:70)at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:370)at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:270)at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.FindWindow(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Well, it's internal,  so you shouldn't build on that. [Here is the source code of `org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS`](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20PI/win32/org/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OS.java) and [here the history](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/commits/master/bundles/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20PI/win32/org/eclipse/swt/internal/win32/OS.java).

Comment: As an internal API this is subject to change without notice. You might be able to rewrite the code to use JNA instead - the `com.sun.jna` and `com.sun.jna.platform` plug-ins are included in recent versions of Eclipse.

Comment: @greg-449 that is what I was looking for. So I tried with newest version of jna-5.13.0 but I couldn't make it. That is why I posted this on here...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Note: You should not try to mix the SWT OS.xxx code with JNA, they may not represent things the same way. Switch completely to JNA.